# Polynomial regression in Python using sklearn, numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make a small program that will plot a graph with best fit line and that will predict the COST value based on inputted SIZE value.

I always get this error, and I do not know what it means:

```
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

This is the graph that I get (red), and I think that curve should look like green curve that i have draw.

[image]

And finally, program makes prediction only when I exit the graph.
What am I doing wrong? 
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size=[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[7],[9],[10],[11],[13]]
cost=[[10],[22],[35],[48],[60],[80],[92],[111],[118],[133]]

def predict(size,cost,x):

    dates=np.reshape(size,(len(size),1))

    svr_poly=SVR(kernel="poly",C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_poly.fit(size,cost)

    plt.scatter(size,cost, color="blue")
    plt.plot(cost, svr_poly.predict(cost), color="red")

    plt.xlabel("Size")
    plt.ylabel("Cost")
    plt.title("prediction")
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()

predictedcost=predict(size,cost,7)

print(predictedcost)
```

Comment: Thats not an error, just a warning. Your current `y` (cost) is of shape (10,1) and it should be (10,). This can be achieved by using `cost = np.array(cost).ravel()` before fitting.

Comment: Ok thanks, a lot. And what about the line. I do not get a proper fit? Line should look like green line, not like red line, right?

Also, what should I do so that I get the predicted value right away, and not when I exit the graph?

Comment: Can you explain more? Also I am not able to get a plot like yours

Comment: It looks like you might be using the wrong tool for the job here, I think there might be some confusion between a polynomial kernel and polynomial features. I would suggest reading [this tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html)

Comment: I have read this, but I do not understand the code. I think there are big difference between my code and the code on the link that you sent me.

Do you maybe know how to fix the problem that I have?

I did the same program, but I used linear regression, and it works perfectly, but I used different tool. The problem is, I do not know how to make polynomial regression with tools that i used for linear regression.

( https://pastebin.com/tkNn6C7T )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I found the answer to this problem. So if you are interested, check it

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

X = np.array([1,2,3,5,6,7,4,7,8,9,5,10,11,7,6,6,10,11,11,12,13,13,14])
Y=np.array([2,3,5,8,11,14,9,19,15,19,15,16,14,7,13,13,14,13,23,25,26,27,33])

koeficienti_polinom = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)

a=koeficienti_polinom[0]
b=koeficienti_polinom[1]
c=koeficienti_polinom[2]

xval=np.linspace(np.min(X), np.max(X))   

regression=a * xval**2 + b*xval + c 

predX = float(input("Enter: "))      
predY = a * predX**2 + b*predX + c   

plt.scatter(X,Y, s=20, color="blue" )      
plt.scatter(predX, predY, color="red")    
plt.plot(xval, regression, color="black", linewidth=1)      

print("Kvadratno predvidjanje: ",round(predY,2))
```